# Django Rest Framework разделение url для API и Web-приложения

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

С API работаю в первый раз, нужен совет опытного человека направить в нужное русло. В проекте есть  приложение Album. Я делаю Web-морду, и API на базе DRF.

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^api/', include('album.urls')),
]
```

**album.urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.AlbumListCreateAPIView.as_view(), name = 'AlbumListCreateAPIView'),
    url(r'^(?P<pk>\d+)/$', views.AlbumRetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView.as_view()),    

]
```

С такими url, по запросу http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/(id) мне отдается список и отдельная модель - все ок. Теперь я хочу получить тоже в WEB интерфейсе. Если я в **album.urls.py** добавлю

```
urlpatterns += [
        url(r'^album/$', views.AlbumList, name = 'AlbumList'),
        url(r'^album/(?P<pk>\d+)$', views.AlbumItem, name = 'AlbumItem'),
 ]
```

То к url будет добавляться **api** (явно лишний здесь)- http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/album/id

Подскажите как правильно разделять настройки в проекте для web и api?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Хорошей практикой считается разделение проекта на приложения. И, в данном примере, лучше API методы вынести в отдельное приложение, тогда префикс /api/ будет у приложений указанных в api.urls, допустим api.album.urls, а без префикса у album.urls.

**core/urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^album/', include('album.urls')),
    url(r'^api/', include('api.urls')),
]
```

**api/urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^album/', include('album.urls')),
]
```

**api/album/urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.AlbumListCreateAPIView.as_view(), name = 'AlbumListCreateAPIView'),
    url(r'^(?P<pk>\d+)/$', views.AlbumRetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView.as_view()),
```

]

**album/urls.py**

```
urlpatterns += [
    url(r'^album/$', views.AlbumList, name = 'AlbumList'),
    url(r'^album/(?P<pk>\d+)$', views.AlbumItem, name = 'AlbumItem'),
 ]
```

Comment: Смысл уловил, спасибо!